# Force Raspberry to get internet from specific network

Tags: networking, ethernet

I configured my RPi to connect to a 3G dongle on boot by setting ppp and wvdial on

```
/etc/network/interfaces
```

The Pi boots up and I have internet connection. Perfect.

Now my problem is that whenever I connect the Pi to my computer via ethernet (using this [tutorial](http://blog.angryturtle.com/2013/02/setting-up-raspberry-pi-for-osx.html)) the internet connection is lost. Even after disconnecting from my computer it stills doesn't connect, I need to reboot so it can get internet connection again.

Is there a way to make the Pi stay connected to the internet through the dongle's interface instead of it trying to make it through the connection to my computer?

Comment: Do both connections use DHCP ?

Comment: What does your ifconfig output look like?

Comment: Setting a higher metric on eth0 than ppp0 should achieve what you want. The lower metric is the higher priority one.

Answer (score 6):

*Assuming your working with linux (raspian, debian, etc...):*

Your asking two different questions, First I'll answer the title question:

#### Force Raspberry to get internet from specific network

I'm going to lock onto your word "network" (as opposed to "interface") and answer this in a pure IP sense:

If you have multiple connections that could provide the internet, you control which will be used via the route table.

To the view the routing table I normally use `netstat -rn` (`-r` is for "show routing", `-n` is for "show me numbers, don't try and do DNS lookups, which might hang if my internet isn't configured right").  A really simple example would look like this:

```
pi@homeServer ~ $ netstat -rn
Kernel IP routing table
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags   MSS Window  irtt Iface
0.0.0.0         192.168.9.1     0.0.0.0         UG        0 0          0 eth0
192.168.9.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.0   U         0 0          0 eth0
172.20.10.0     0.0.0.0         255.255.255.240 U         0 0          0 wlan0
pi@homeServer ~ $
```

The line in that output that shows which way IP packets will go is the line with a dest of `0.0.0.0` and a genmask of `0.0.0.0`, that is normally known as the `default route` (a mask of `0.0.0.0` is all wildcard, thats really the marker of a default route), and as it currently points to a specific address in the `192.168.9' range, internet traffic will go via ethernet interface.

If I want to switch my internet to the other network I would (as root) use the `route` command, and in this case, given that my wifi connection isn't point-to-point I must know the ip address of the router that can forward traffic out of that network (In my case that is `172.20.10.1`) so I would do:

1. Delete the current default route

   ```
   sudo route del default
   ```
2. Add a new default route for the other network

   ```
   sudo route add default gw 172.20.10.1
   ```

> FYI while `route` is what I use, I see the some consider it deprecated and instead recommend using the `ip route` command, see @Fred 's comment below for syntax. [reference for deprecation](https://serverfault.com/questions/523388/what-is-the-difference-between-route-and-ip-route)

#### Is there a way stay connected through the dongle's interface

Its been a while since I've worked with `ppp` and `wvdial`, and without configs (or at least references to the guides you followed in setting them up) its *really* hard to guess which problems your running into, but as a few ideas:

- Is the connection really down or did you just lose your default route when your eth0 came up?

  - Check this in both `netstat -rn` and `ifconfig`.
  - Is an interface in `netstat -rn`? if so, is there a default route to it?
  - In `ifconfig` do you see interface for the dongle (likely `ppp`)? is it `UP`?
- I can't remember where `ppp`/`wvdial` log, but that should be checked.  That log will tell you connection state, and should let you know if the whole system has shut down for some reason
- If you see an interface, try to `ping` something (... anything ...) on it, and see if the connection comes up.

  - I know the `ppp`/`wvdial` combo has some automatic connection capability (depending on configuration)

    - So if the connection came up with a ping (or the connection has stayed up the whole time): it could be the (ppp) default route got lost when you brought up the ethernet.
    - If this is the problem you would just need to add a default route and the whole system would come back online.

Comment: `ip route` doesn't quite use the same syntax. However, you can copy and paste it's output to use as input. For example, if it shows `default via 192.168.9.1 dev eth0`, you can remove that route simply by executing `ip route del default via 192.168.9.1 dev eth0`. You can easily use the output as a template to add new commands, e.g. `ip route add default via 172.20.10.1 dev wlan0`.